# Exercise 6.6.5 (b) of Marker's "Model Theory"

Tags: model-theory

I am working through some exercises in Marker's model theory book. I have a question about exercise 6.6.5 (b):

> Let $\mathcal L = \{R\}$, where $R$ is a ternary relation symbol. Suppose that $V$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. We view $V$ as an $\mathcal L$-structure by interpreting $R$ as $\{ (a,b,c) : a + b + c = 0 \}$. Show that the $\mathcal L$-theory of $V$ is uncountably categorical and the prime model has dimension 2.

My argument is this:

- Zero is implicitly definable as the unique $z$ satisfying $R(z,z,z)$
- Then $-a$ is the unique element satisfying $R(a,-a,0)$
- And $a+b$ is the unique element satisfying $R(-a,-b,a+b)$
- Any formula involving scalar multiplication by rationals can have its denominators cleared and be written with negation and repeated addition

So every formula in usual $\mathbb Q$-vector space theory is equivalent to one in the $\mathcal L$-theory, and the prime model in the $\mathcal L$-theory should also just be $\mathbb Q$, and should also have dimension 1. Why is my argument wrong? Why does the prime model have dimension 2?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thank you for the response. I do know that he means dimension as the minimal size of the basis for the associated pregeometry, but I think you're right my argument kind of skipped over this step. However, it seems to me that because every formula in the usual $\mathbb Q$-vector space theory is equivalent to one in the $\mathcal L$-theory and vice-versa, that a basis in the usual $\mathbb Q$-vector space theory should also be a basis in the $\mathcal L$-theory and vice-versa.

Comment: hi jacob; indeed, I agree with your analysis and am wondering whether this is a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument seems correct. I think this is a mistake in Marker.

I suspect that what Marker had in mind was to equip $\mathbb{Q}$ with its natural [heap](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/heap) structure: a ternary *function* symbol $t$ interpreted as $t(x,y,z) = x-y+z$.

The point is that for any $q\in \mathbb{Q}$, the structure $(\mathbb{Q};t,q)$ is interdefinable with a structure isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q};0,+)$, defining $0$ as $q$ and $x+z$ as $t(x,q,z)$. This is enough to show that $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{Q};t)$ is uncountably categorical with prime model $(\mathbb{Q};t)$, and that $\mathrm{acl}(q) = \{q\}$, so the prime model has dimension $2$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you!